# Trouble with UTF-8 input

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++17, utf-16, wstring

My simple code has no trouble with Japanese characters when outputting, but for some reason it doesn't take input properly, is it lacking something?

```
int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);

std::wstring s = L"こんにちは, 世界!\nHello, World!";
std::wcout << s << endl;
std::wstring test;

getline(wcin, test);

std::wstring test2 = test;
std::wcout << test2 << endl;

std::wstring test3 = test2;
std::wcout << test3 << endl;
std::wcout << "Press ENTER to exit.";
std::wcout << "\n";
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything here where you would be using UTF-8. You're using `wchar_t`s, which are not UTF-8. Code pages don't apply to `wchar_t` input.

Comment: Your code lacks a properly functioning OS. Unicode input in Windows console does not work, and this isn't likely to change any time soon.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Untrue or Japanese Windows users would have an issue.  My answer works.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Hmm looks like I've confused it with UTF-8 input which isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me in the Windows 10 command prompt.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);  // or _O_U16TEXT, either work
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);

    wstring s = L"こんにちは, 世界!\nHello, World!";
    wcout << s << endl;

    wstring test;
    getline(wcin, test);
    wcout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\>test
こんにちは, 世界!
Hello, World!
你好马克！                << input line
你好马克！
```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't know about stdin.