# Is there a proper way to receive input from console in UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, utf-8, character-encoding

When getting input from `std::cin` in windows, the input is apparently always in the encoding windows-1252 (the default for the host machine in my case) despite all the configurations made, that apparently only affect to the output. Is there a proper way to capture input in windows in UTF-8 encoding?

For instance, let's check out this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cin.imbue(locale("es_ES.UTF-8"));
    std::cout.imbue(locale("es_ES.UTF-8"));

    std::cout << "ñeñeñe> ";
    std::string in; 
    std::getline( std::cin, in ); 
    std::cout << in; 

}
```

I've compiled it using visual studio 2022 in a windows machine with spanish locale. The source code is in UTF-8. When executing the resulting program (windows powershell session, after executing `chcp 65001` to set the default encoding to UTF-8), I see the following:

```
PS C:\> .\test_program.exe
ñeñeñe> ñeñeñe
 e e e
```

The first "ñeñeñe" is correct: it display correctly the "ñ" caracter to the output console. So far, so good. The user input is echoed back to the console correctly: another good point. But! when it turns to send back the encoded string to the ouput, the "ñ" caracter is substituted by an empty space.

When debugging this program, I see that the variable "in" have captured the input in an encoding that it is not utf-8: for the "ñ" it use only one character, whereas in utf-8 that caracter must consume two. The conclusion is that the input is not affect for the `chcp` command. Is something I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Somebody have asked me to see what happens when changing to wcout/wcin:

```
std::wcout << u"ñeñeñe> ";
std::wstring in;
std::getline(std::wcin, in);
std::wcout << in;
```

Behaviour:

```
PS C:\> .\test.exe
0,000,7FF,6D1,B76,E30ñeñeñe
 e e e
```

Other try (setting the string as L"ñeñeñe"):

```
Ã±eÃ±eÃ±e> ñeñeñe
 e e e
```

Leaving it as is:

```
std::wcout << "ñeñeñe> ";
```

Result is:

```
eee>
```

Comment: Have you tried `wcin`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, and got some.... let's say flowery results. If using wcin, wcout only, the input string is output back as rubbish, because is encoded internally as ¿maybe UTF-16? and send back as utf-16 when the expected string should be in utf-8. I can update the question accordingly if you want

Comment: Yes, I think that's helpful to tell a) that you know about it and b) it does not solve the problem.

Comment: It seems it's really that bad: https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/#utf8_mode_input

Comment: Definitely that's the problem.

Comment: I wonder if it's a workaround for this, like using a windows forms or something like that that emulates a console. The problem is I want to create a simple console application that accepts and returns UTF-8 and it seems an impossible thing

Comment: It is not impossible but you might have to do it yourself with the CRT.

Comment: @Anders, I really doubt that nobody have ever bumped on this. How it's done in Java, for instance??? AFAIK, java is compiled in C and internally their strings are UTF-8, so some kind of conversion is made behind the scenes

Comment: @RaulLuna: it uses different method. Consoles read the keys and translate into characters to send to the program. Many programs go in the hard way: read the scan code, interpret the keyboard, find which character you get.

Comment: microsoft recently implemented pty API. It included also a series of blog post, which were interesting: it told us that many programs just put a console outside visible desktop )with active keyboard) and grab images of that console, because there were no other way to have reliable interface. Ugly.

Comment: I meant to say without the CRT. Meaning, `ReadFile` on `GetStdHandle`. You of course have to convert the input bytes yourself if they are not already UTF-8.

Comment: You can use `_setmode` on both stdout and stdin to read wide strings that you could convert to UTF-8.  See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65816756/235698) helps you.

Comment: Yes, @MarkTolonen, I've tried that way, but the results are not satisfactory (see my own answer). The funny part is because the program is stored -or compiled, I don't know- into UTF-8, the string is converted into funny ways, resulting in rubbish most of the time

Comment: The best solution I've come so far come from the example program in this page: https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/#utf8_mode_input. This allows to 1) enter the literal strings in unicode, 2) input text in unicode and the output will be in unicode also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest to the solution I've found so far:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);

    std::wcout << L"ñeñeñe";
    std::wstring in;
    std::getline(std::wcin, in);
    std::wcout << in;

    return 0;
}
```

The solution [depicted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65810752/stdwcout-printing-unicode-characters-but-they-are-hidden/65816756#65816756) went in the right direction. Problem: both stdin and stdout should be in the same configuration, because the echo of the console rewrites the input. The problem is the writing of the string with \uXXXX codes.... I am guessing how to overcome that or using `#define`'s to overcome and clarify the text literals

Comment: Send wide strings to`wcout` (`L"你好"`). You don’t have to use escape code if you save the source in UTF-8 and set the compiler source charset to  UTF-8 if not the default. `/utf-8` on MSVC compiler.