Windows doesn't want to detect accents c++
I'm making a program in C++ where I need to detect accents and macrons, so áéíóúāēīōūȳ. I'm using Windows 11. I use getline(cin, input) and if the input has any macron or accent it treats it as a blank character, ágȳ = g.
I'm using the powershell terminal with chcp 65001, it displays correctly the accents with cout but does not recive the input correctly.
Here's is some code:
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Set the console to UTF-8 encoding
    // system("chcp 65001 > nul");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8"); // Ensure UTF-8 encoding

    string a;
    cout << "Write here āēīōū (with accents and macrons):" << endl;

    // Capture input with getline
    getline(cin, a);

    cout << endl << "You wrote: " << a << endl;

    // Compare the input with a specific character
    if (a == "á") {
        cout << "It's the same!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "It's not the same." << endl;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        cout << "a[i]: " << a[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}


Windows doesn't suck (or at least is not your problem). You also have to ensure the encoding of your source code is UTF-8 (or 16). if you have problems use the full escaped sequence for  á  (Unicode Character “á” (U+00E1)).

"I wasted a lot of time, so don't redirect me to some unresponded question to get more karma" - commenters and people answering will do whatever they please. You don't get to tell people how to respond.

Check if setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8"); is working on your system.

Have you tried using a debugger to verify whether a is receiving the correct utf-8 bytes?

UTF-8 console input is broken in Windows (or was broken until recently). UTF-16 however has always worked (with wchar_t).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71465484/is-there-a-proper-way-to-receive-input-from-console-in-utf-8-encoding and https://github.com/Jalopy-Tech/WUTF8Console

Your console input may be set to UTF-8, but is your .cpp file saved in UTF-8 as well? Perhaps the encoding of the string literal "á" does not match the encoding of the console input even if they logically represent the same character.

@RemyLebeau It is rather improbable that OP's C++ file is saved in UTF-8 when doing output, but not in UTF-8 when doing input.

You also will get different results with different compilers.

Are you using the /utf-8 compiler flag?

I'm using the new Terminal app from Microsoft, and I get right input and output for each character:
if (a == "ȳ") { 


Write here āēīōū (with accents and macrons):
ȳ

You wrote: ȳ
It's the same!
a[i]:

The reason why the iteration in the end of the code doesn't work is really simple: std::string stores utf8 characters in multiple bytes sequence (char AFAIK). You can't just rip utf8 symbol from the sequence std::string points to.
Changing to cout << "a[i]: " << a << endl; fixes the problem:
Write here āēīōū (with accents and macrons):
āēīōū

You wrote: āēīōū
It's not the same.
a[i]: āēīōū

P.S: Quote from std::string wikipedia page:

The individual units making up the string are of type char, at least (and almost always) 8 bits each. In modern usage these are often not "characters", but parts of a multibyte character encoding such as UTF-8.


"std::string stores utf8 characters in multiple bytes sequence" - std::string has no concept of character encodings. Each char is a raw byte in whatever encoding the characters are using.  If the characters are encoding in UTF-8, then yes, non-ASCII characters will occupy more than 1 char each. But, if the same characters are encoded in Windows-125x for example, then the characters will be 1 char each.

You do need chcp 65001 in the new console. setlocale or std::locale::global or anything locale-related won't help to get the input working (but it can be nice/necessary for other things). This is with MSVC, other compilers may do things differently.

Yeah, but that's what i said. The characters are stored in a continious bytes sequence (e.g. chars).
Quote from [std::string wikipedia page] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_string_handling): "The individual units making up the string are of type char, at least (and almost always) 8 bits each. In modern usage these are often not "characters", but parts of a multibyte character encoding such as UTF-8".
